# Ionic App (using ngResource) with RESTful Laravel API getting net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, ionic-framework, ngresource

I've used this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/593726/is-it-possible-to-run-chrome-with-and-without-web-security-at-the-same-time/593732#593732) to disable web security in Chrome so I can have localhost:8100 served by Ionic and localhost:8000 served by Laravel communicate without XSS issues, but now I'm getting this error in my Chrome console:

```
POST localhost:8000/api/user net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

I found a couple different solutions for this, but they all seem to be related to third-party services being used on mobile devices (ex. OAuth), old Chromium bugs, or a few Chrome apps, but I'm just trying to round trip with my RESTful endpoints using Ionic/AngularJS ngResource and Laravel's RESTful routing in my development environment.

I'm using an interceptor to switch between asset and API requests:

```
.factory('API', ['ConfigSettings',
    function (ConfigSettings) {

        var service = {
            request: function (config) {

                if (config.url.indexOf("/api") > -1) {
                    config.url = ConfigSettings.host + ':' + ConfigSettings.port + config.url;
                }

                return config;
            }
        }

        return service;
    }])

.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('API');
}]);
```

Anyone know what this error means in my case and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you set 'http'as protocol or a '//' in front of the server name?

Comment: Nice! that's was totally it.  I've now moved onto the next error in my array of errors trying to get this to work where I'm now getting: POST http://localhost:8000/api/user 500 (Internal Server Error); and Laravel's CLI is returning [Sun Jun 14 22:57:09 2015] ::1:51788 Invalid request (Unexpected EOF).  Thanks @Michael for the fix, any idea about the next one.  Either way if you drop this as the answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi @Michael, in case it helps when I hit http://localhost:8000/api/user in a separate window I get my "Hello World" response string.  So the endpoint is valid, but get a 500 Error through requests from app.

Comment: Not sure about the second error. When you call the URL from a separate window it will do a GET request, but the POST request fails? Do you see an error on the server side? Can you post the request headers here? Maybe the content-length isn't correct or missing or the content isn't correct itself.

Comment: Hi @Michael, since you answered this question (though not yet officially), and I couldn't find a similar question with this answer I thought it would be better to post the next error as a new question as it doesn't appear to be related - http://stackoverflow.com/q/30851877/1148107.