# Clean Laravel 5.1 Install with a single RESTful route getting NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 as an API for an Ionic app, and it appears to be almost working, but my test route in Laravel

```
Route::group( [ 'prefix' => 'api' ], function ()
{
    Route::any( 'user', function ()
    {
        return 'Hello Anonymous User';
    } );
} );
```

When I hit

```
http://localhost:8000/api/user
```

Should just return "Hello Anonymous User", but since switching to Homestead instead of using artisan serve it now throws this error:

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:
in RouteCollection.php line 145
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 719
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 210
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 111
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

And any post from Ionic using ngResource to the API is returned as a 500 Error in the console.  I found one solution that suggested turning off VerifyCsrfToken middleware in app/http/Kernel.php by commenting out:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

but this didn't work or change the error.

I am able to hit the default welcome route at http://localhost:8000/ and see the Laravel 5 welcome view with debugbar.  I also tried using just the inner route form above without the group and hit http://localhost:8000/user, but it produces the same error.

**UPDATE**

Checking the route list all the routes appear to be okay.

```
php artisan route:list

| GET|HEAD                       | /                 | Closure
| GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | api/user          | Closure
| GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | user              | Closure

... with debugbar routes
```

Comment: looks correct, have you tried without the group to see if it works? maybe a possible issue with the htaccess

Comment: Hi @DavidNguyen, I just tried pulling out the inner user route from the group and hit http://localhost:8000/user, but I get the exact same error.

Comment: Hi @DavidNguyen, if it helps I am able to hit the welcome route at http://localhost:8000/.

Comment: Sounds like htaccess issue, are you using apache? or something else.

Comment: @mtplutz voted up, because i would like to know the solution.

Comment: @DavidNguyen I'm using the default Homestead VM with Nginx and MySQL.

Comment: Sure sounds like an `.htaccess` issue, but since you're using Homestead it should just work... Two thoughts: 1) what is the output of `php artisan route:list`? Is your route listed there? 2) this probably won't make any difference, but does it work when you visit `http://localhost:8000/index.php/api/user`?

Comment: @Kryten the route list appears to be correct with respect to the test routes I have in place (I posted the output above), and I get the same error using the not so pretty URL syntax (good idea to check though I had just assumed since I'm using Homestead)

Comment: Are you sure that welcome route is in the same project? If you put a `dd('here') ` on top of your routes file, do you see that? By default homestead would be homestead.app/api/user if I am not mistaken. That is provided that you added `192.1168.10.10 homestead.app` to your OS hosts file.

Comment: Think pevara is right, typo though: 192.168.10.10

Comment: Since you're able to see the welcome page, and not the sub routes. I'd suggest `var_dump(\Request::all())` right before registering these routes. Then try both routes. It might give us a more clear idea.

Comment: @Pevara you're absolutely right, it wasn't looking at the right project there was no output from dd().  The domain I had used in hosts was a copy-paste of an Apache project, so was 127.0.0.1, instead of 192.168.10.10, but that didn't even matter since I was still trying to hit http://localhost:8000/api/user like I was earlier this morning before I switched from "artisan serve" to "homestead".  Just a chain of errors in implementation, thanks so much for the help.  If you post that as the answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Voting this up because your question is detailed and clear

Answer (score 1):

If it works with artisan serve instead of homestead then it is likely that your homestead hosts setup is sending your request to the default project on homestead instead of the one that you have setup. Please confirm that dd("ping") at the top of your routes file shows up on screen. Otherwise, you are likely looking at the wrong app.

Check your /etc/hosts file on your machine (assuming OS X or *nix) and make sure you've setup 192.168.10.10 to point to someappname.app and in your ~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml make sure in the sites: section you have added

```
-map: someappname.app
 to: /home/whatever the mapped path to this app is
```

From within your ~/Homestead directory, type vagrant provision to make sure vagrant takes up the latest changes.

I think this should solve your problem.